# Trouble casting an interface to an implemented class

Tags: java, interface, casting

Here is my class:

```
public class LinkedListSet implements Set {
    private class Node  //much easier as a private class; don't have to extend
    {
        private int data;
        private Node next;
        public Node (){}
        public Node (int x)
        {
            data = x;
        }

        public int data()
        {
            return data;
        }

        public Node next()
        {
        return next;
        }

    }

    private Node first;
    private int Size;
    private int whichList; //used to identify the particular LL object
```

Here is my interface:

```
public interface Set {
    public boolean isEmpty();            
    public void makeEmpty();            
    public boolean isMember(int x); 
    public void add(int x);    
    public void remove(int y);            
    public void union(Set other, Set result); 
    public void intersection (Set other, Set result); 
    public void difference (Set other, Set result); 
    @Override
    public String toString(); 

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other); 

    public void setList(int i); //i added this to use it as an identifier for each
                            //list element in the set array

    public String getListId(); //these two extra methods make life easier

}
```

I have a method like this (in the `LinkedListSet` class):

```
 public void difference (Set other, Set result)
 {
     if (other.isEmpty())
     {
         System.out.println("The set is empty before cast");
     }
     LinkedListSet othr = (LinkedListSet) other;
     LinkedListSet res = (LinkedListSet) result;
     if (this.isEmpty() || othr.isEmpty())
     {
         if (othr.isEmpty())
             System.out.println("The set is empty after cast");
         if (this.isEmpty())
             System.out.println("This is also empty");
         return;
     }
     differenceHelper(this.first, othr.first, res);
     result = res;
 }// the print statements were added for debugging
```

The problem is, in the above method I am unable to cast the `Set Other` into its linked list implementation. When I call this method in the main program, the parameter is actually of type linked list (so I don't get any errors obviously).

However, all the instance variables are `null`. The list is empty before and after I cast it (when it actually isn't empty). I know this is because the interface doesn't include any information about the `Nodes`, but is there anything I can do other than editing the interface to incorporate the `Node`?

I hope I've made this clear enough. Any help would be appreciated.

edit:
In the main program I created an array of Sets.

```
    Set[] sets = new Set[7];
    for (int i = 0; i< sets.length; i++) //initialize each element
    {
        sets[i] = new LinkedListSet();
    }
```

each list has nodes with data values which are added on later on in the code...

then I call the difference method.

```
      sets[0].difference(sets[1], sets[4])
```

sets[1].isEmpty returns true for some reason (even though it is not).

If I were to do something like:
System.out.println(sets[1].first.data()) I would have no problem whatsoever.
For some reason all the values become null when the parameters are passed to the difference method.

```
    public boolean isEmpty()
{
  return first == null;
}
```

Comment: Please add the `LinkListSet` difference method implementation code. Also the code where you are instantiating and using these classes. Maybe you are doing something wrong there.

Comment: It's not the implementation code that's wrong.

Comment: The problem is within the method. I checked.

Comment: sorry I just noticed your `difference` method implementation.

Comment: when you call isEmpty on the other set in your main code does it return false?

Comment: It returns true before and after the casting.

Comment: even though it's not empty. If i get the LinkedList object by itself and check if it's empty, it would return false as expected.

Comment: Let me add the line of code I have in the main program..

Comment: Also your isEmpty implementation please.

Comment: Well you don't need to know isEmpty, when I output all the values manually, there are none. But alright I'll post it

Comment: Are you saying that in your main method code `System.out.println(sets[1].first.data())` prints a valid integer but `sets[1].isEmpty()` returns true?

Comment: No. sets[1].isEmpty() returns false.

Comment: it only returns true when passed as a parameter in: set[0].difference(set[1], set[4]) for some reason.

Comment: I found out the problem. It was a  bug in my input (main program).

Comment: I'm really sorry if I made you think to much. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested what you are trying to do with the following code and I see no problems:

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class RandomCastTest {

    public interface Set {
        boolean isEmpty();

        void add(int x);

        void difference(Set other, Set result);

        @Override
        String toString();

        @Override
        boolean equals(Object other);
    }

    public class LinkedListSet implements Set {
        private class Node  //much easier as a private class; don't have to extend
        {
            private int data;
            private Node next;

            public Node() {
            }

            public Node(int x) {
                data = x;
            }

            public int data() {
                return data;
            }

            public Node next() {
                return next;
            }

            public void next(Node node) {
                next = node;
            }
        }

        private Node first;
        private int Size;
        private int whichList; //used to identify the particular LL object

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return first == null;
        }

        @Override
        public void add(int x) {
            Node node = new Node(x);

            if (first == null) {
                first = node;
            } else {
                Node currentNode;
                Node nextNode = first;
                do {
                    currentNode = nextNode;
                    nextNode = currentNode.next();
                } while (nextNode != null);

                currentNode.next(node);
            }
            Size++;
        }

        @Override
        public void difference(Set other, Set result) {
            if (other.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("The set is empty before cast");
            }
            LinkedListSet othr = (LinkedListSet) other;
            LinkedListSet res = (LinkedListSet) result;
            if (this.isEmpty() || othr.isEmpty()) {
                if (othr.isEmpty())
                    System.out.println("The set is empty after cast");
                if (this.isEmpty())
                    System.out.println("This is also empty");
                return;
            }
            result = res;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Set[] sets = new Set[7];
        for (int i = 0; i < sets.length; i++) {
            sets[i] = new LinkedListSet();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            sets[1].add(i);
        }

        for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
            sets[0].add(i);
        }

        sets[0].difference(sets[1], sets[4]);
        // ... find difference
    }
}
```

To simplify I removed unimplemented methods from the interface. Also added the `add` method implementation. Please see if it works for you.

Comment: You welcome. Thanks for the SO points ;). So what was the problem?